# How can I SSH into an Ubuntu server from outside of my LAN?

Tags: ubuntu, ssh

I have a new Ubuntu server.  I can ssh into it from within my LAN, but cannot from outside of my LAN.  Firestarter has not been installed.  OpenSSH is installed and running.  Output from netstat -pant shows (among a few other things):

tcp6 0 0 :::22 :::* LISTEN 4593/sshd

Any clue as to how I can SSH in from off site?

Thanks in advance!

Comment: Does your router know that it should allow/redirect SSH traffic to your Ubuntu server?

Answer (score 2):

To do this you need to forward a port from your router to the computer you wish to connect to.

This involves setting a port for the router to listen on as well as an ip address and port to forward that traffic to.

So if you wish to use the default port of 22 then the rule would look something like the following.

22 192.168.0.56:22

Comment: Unless he's filtering or firewalling on the computer itself, it's probably set from a web interface to his router...just a guess that he's running something like a Linksys or Dlink or something like that, from teh sounds of it.

Comment: Sometimes port/address translation implies creating a filtering rule on the firewall to allow traffic to pass also.

Answer (score 0):

You need to set up your router to forward TCP port 22 from your Internet link to your server's internal IP address.

Answer (score -1):

Try [reverse SSH tunnel](http://www.howtoforge.com/reverse-ssh-tunneling)